# What is the equivalent of hashing Java code into C#?

Tags: java, c#, hash, hmac, sha512

I have a strange problem in getting equivalent hash code from C# code translated into Java. I don't know, what MessageDigest update method do. It should only update the contents of digest and should compute hash after calling digest.

Same thing I am doing in C# with SHAManaged512.ComputeHash(content). But I am not getting same hash code.

**Following is the Java code.**

```
public static String hash(String body, String secret) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] bytes = md.digest(secret.getBytes("UTF-8")); 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

**Following is C# Code**

```
private byte[] ComputeContentHash(string contentBody)
{               
        using (var shaM = new SHA512Managed())       
        {
            var content = string.Concat(contentBody, Options.SecretKey);

            var hashedValue = shaM.ComputeHash(ToJsonStream(content));
            return hashedValue;
        }
}

public static Stream ToJsonStream(object obj)
{
   return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(obj.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Its been two years since you asked but just in case someone comes across this question, here's the solution

```
public static string encryptHash(string APIkey, string RequestBodyJson)
    {
        var secretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(APIkey);
        var saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestBodyJson);

        using (var sHA256 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            byte[] bytes = sHA256.ComputeHash(saltBytes.Concat(secretBytes).ToArray());

            //convert to hex
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put first Secret Key and concate it with pay load data.

Answer (score -1):

`Encoding.Unicode` (which you are using in the C# `ToJsonStream` method) is not UTF8. It's UTF16. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx). (Also keep in mind that UTF16 can be little or big endian.) You're looking for `Encoding.UTF8`.

First thing to do is check if the byte array you're hashing is the same.

Comment: Thanks for comments.
I did it on my own. The problem was to append at C# side Secret Key first and then Content.

Comment: @Usman In that case, you can accept your own answer. As for my answer, it still holds. I don't know how it works for you since UTF8 is generally different that UTF16 and you are evidently using UTF8 in Java and UTF16 in C#.